# Possible to create a shortcut in Windows 7 to a mounted network drive in XP Mode?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp-mode

I'm using an application that mounts a remotely hosted directory as a drive in Windows. Unfortunately, it doesn't run under 64-bit Windows 7.

Using Windows 7's "XP Mode," though, the app works just fine in this virtualized 32-bit environment. The mounted drive displays and is accessible in XP Mode's virtualized XP environment. However, what I would *really* like is to open the mounted network drive in XP Mode directly from Windows 7 (even if I can't drag and drop).

XP Mode allows you to launch applications installed in the virtualized XP environment from shortcuts in Windows 7. However, I can't find a way to launch Windows Explorer or specific mapped drives on the virtualized XP environment from shortcuts in Windows 7.

Can anyone provide instructions to create a shortcut in Windows 7 to a network drive mapped in the virtualized XP environment of XP Mode?